# jquery.mobile, isolate from other pages etc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm using asp.net web forms. I have DynamicDataField with some jquery.mobile widjets:

```
   <head>
       <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-     1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">   </script>
<script>
    function go() {
  ////some code
   };
 </script>
 </head>
 <div>
 <div data-role="rangeslider" class="searchBlock">
  <label for="range-1a">Комнат:</label>
   <input name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="0" type="range"    class="seearchSlider" />
   <label for="range-1b">Rangeslider:</label>
   <input name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="50" value="100" type="range" class="seearchSlider" />
 </div>
 ///etc, several same divs
```

this DynamicDataField(Search.ascx) I place on my Main.Master padge:

```
 <%@ Register Src="~/DynamicData/FieldTemplates/Search.ascx" TagPrefix="search" TagName="search" %>
 <head runat="server">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="/Content/MainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title></title>

 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="left">
        <div style="background: #fff">
             <search:search id="menu2" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

The problem is: after adding

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">   </script>
```

all my project starts behave strange. All fonts etc are like as in jquery.mobile widjet, some javascript methods don't work. So. How can I isolate jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js? I want it to be used ONLY in Search.ascx.
Any suggestions? sry, i'm new in jquery:)

Answer (score 0):

By default, jQuery Mobile enhances everything on the page. You can use `data-enhance="false` on the page body, and just use `data-enhance="true"` on the control that you want to enhance.

See [the docs](http://devdocs.io/jquerymobile/global-config) for more info.

Comment: <body  data-enhance="false"> like this?

Comment: Solved my problem: <script>
         $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
             $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
             $.extend($.mobile, {
                 ajaxEnabled: false
             });
         });
    </script>

Comment: but how can I block jquery.mobile.css?

Comment: @user2970104 You can't really block a css file that's included on the page from being applied to some elements but not others. The only option you have is to avoid having classes that collide with the classes used by jQM or you can have your own CSS classes that override them.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to tell JQM not to to auto-initialize pages. You should do that once `mobileinit` fires to apply global changes, after loading jQuery and before loading jQuery mobile JS libraries.

Nevertheless, bu doing so, you will need to manually enhance JQM elements (widgets).

```
<head>
  <!-- jQuery.js here -->
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    });
  </script>
  <!-- jQuery Mobile.js here -->
</head>
```